# Rails Routing w/ Passenger - How to get passenger to pay attention to root route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a root route setup in my app, which works fine on a local webrick server. (localhost:3000/ brings up the home page).

On my nginx/passenger server, though, it's looking for inside the public folder, and not paying attention to the route I have setup to redirect the root - so instead I'm getting a not-found error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include your passenger configuration inside your nginx.conf file?

Comment: Please post lines related to passenger in your nginx configuration file.